# Laravel / Eloquent - How Do You Add An Additional wherePivot() Condition To An updateExistingPivot() Call?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a reference table with the following columns:

```
-user_id (foreign key)
-location_id (foreign key)
-skill_level
-court_id
```

I can update the `skill_level` pivot column value in the above table with:

```
$user = User::find($user_id)
$user->locations()->updateExistingPivot($location_id, array(
    'skill_level' => $new_value
));
```

I would like to add something akin to a `wherePivot()` to the above so that only records that matches a certain `court_id` (in addition to `user_id` and `location_id`) are updated.  Something similar to:

```
->wherePivot('court_id', '=', $court_id);
```

How would I do this with an `updateExistingPivot()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using `newPivotStatement()` - which allows you to start a chain of statements off of the pivot table.

Instead of using `updateExistingPivot()`, the call would look like:

```
$user->locations()->newPivotStatement()->where('location_id', '=', $location_id)  
     ->where('court_id', '=', $court_id)->update(array(
    'skill_level' => $new_value
));
```